# how to insert form data to mysql using sockets in PHP | jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sockets

i am new to web sockets and i want to to insert form data to mysql database using web sockets 
Can anyone please help me to do that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You May Reefer http://www.php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php

Comment: Include some of the code that you have tried or currently have.

Answer (score 1):

Sockets are used to for interprocess communication between server and clients or TCP,UDP Connections. But is a bad idea/usage to use to insert data to mysql.

Instead of scokets u can use php to insert data into mysql which is the most common and widely accepted method and very easy to use.

A sample code which shows u how this works .

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $servername="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $db="login";
    //connection
    $conn=new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$db);
    //fetch from form
    $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['usernam']);
    $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']);
    $myemail=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email']);      
    $sql=$conn->query("INSERT INTO su values('$myusername','$mypassword','$myemail',0)");

    }
?>
```

Hope this Post helped u!!!

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Rohan

Comment: If the post was helpful please mark it Correct or upvote it thanks